# Android Design Principle for most used fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am designing an Android Application in Android where there is one entry point activity which has 3 TABS and I need to allow user to update his status from any of the Tabs. So, I have created a StatusFragment in activity_main.xml. So it is available at the top of each fragment in tabs. I just wanted to ask if there is a better way of doing this. I want to minimize the screen estate used by Status Fragment. Here goes my StatusFragment's layout xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_dark"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:dividerPadding="@dimen/list_view_item_image_padding"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="@dimen/list_view_item_image_padding">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_status"
    android:padding="@dimen/list_view_item_image_padding"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/list_view_item_image_margin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/iv_edit_status"
    android:padding="@dimen/list_view_item_image_padding"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/list_view_item_image_margin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_edit"
    android:background="@drawable/list_view_button_selector"
    />
```

Sory for bad english. If I'm at wrong place please guide me to the right one. Any help provided will be helpful.
I have thought of doing it in a NavigationDrawer and SlidingPaneLayout but I guess these layouts are overkill for this task.

Comment: You can use the navigation drawer or sliding menu to have a hidden pane on the side of your main activity. The user can slide it out while remaining on any tab and update the status there.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the status as part of the main activity and just change the fragment corresponding to the tab inside of a frame layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView/>
        <ImageButton/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_container"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```